# Handle 0 value from json

Tags: ios, json

I want to handle int value which are coming from the json and that is 0.
Here is my code but it's not working and my app is crashing at run time.

```
UILabel *like=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
if ([[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"likes"] == (id)[NSNull null]) {
    like.text=@"-";
}
  else{
    like.text=[[json                                               objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"feed_text"];
}
```

and here is my Response

```
{
            "feed_id": "2",
            "group_id": "1",
            "group_name": "Church",
            "feed_text": "Hi+this+is+my+first+Post+in+Church+group",
            "likes": 0,
            "comments": 0,
            "latitude": "21.180407400000000000",
            "longitude": "66308dbc30ae53223f1213f793700381"
        }
```

anyone has any idea how to handle zero value ?
Thank you

Comment: What error message are you seeing when your app crashes?

Comment: `[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"likes"]` class is `NSNumber` or `NSString`? I guess you've got a "unrecognized selector" crash error message, talking about a NSString method sent to `NSNumber`  or something like that.

Comment: @donnywals ths is my error log

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000023'

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final code which i used to handle 0 value from json...

```
UILabel *like=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
NSString *lbllike =[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"likes"];
like.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lbllike];
```

you just have to pass whatever is your parameter and set tag on UILabel for example i have set 11 and its work like a charm.
i hope it will usefull.

Thank You

Comment: Success  =200,
InvalidAuthentication=400,
UnAuthorized=401,
InternalServerError=500,
ConnectionTimeOutError=1000,

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"likes"] intValue]==0) {
    like.text=@"-";
}
else{
    like.text=[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"feed_text"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global variable Bool flag;
flag=true;



- (IBAction)buttonHandlerTreatmentPointImageChange:(BLButton *)sender {
    __block CATransform3D transform;
    if (flag)
    {
        flag=false;
        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI / 1.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }
    else
    {
         flag=true;
        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        transform.m34 = 1.0f / 2500.0f;
        self.viewToFlip.layer.transform = transform;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {  
    }];
}
```